# Is there a way to identify when a 'like' was put on a blog post?

Tags: django

I've got a standard blog post set up where users can like posts. I'd like to be able to work out which posts have had the most likes in a given time frame but I'm not sure how to identify when a like was attributed to a post.

My `Post` model:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    objects = PostManager()
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="post_like", blank=True)
```

Other posts I've seen with a similar question have a `Like` model, is there a way I can do what I want using my current model or do I need to create a separate model for it? I was hoping to do something like adding `auto_now_add=True` to my `likes` attribute, similar to what I've done with `date`, but I know that only tells me when a blog post object was created.

Comment: Not with a `ManyToMany` without a `through` model no.

Answer (score 1):

Not with a `ManyToMany` without a `through` model no. But nothing stops us from making one. Indeed:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    objects = PostManager()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        default=None,
        null=True,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='post_like',
        blank=True,
        through='PostLike',
    )


class PostLike(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liker = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

We can then get the `PostLike`s of a `Post` with:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

posts = Post.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('postlike_set', PostLike.objects.select_related('liker'))
)

for post in posts:
    for postlike in post.postlike_set.all():
        print(f'like for {post} by {postlike.liker} on {postlike.created_at}')
```